# How can I center an image with display: grid

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center an image inside of the 'display: grid' but it's not working.

[Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UBCS.png)

I've tried 'align-items' but I didn't work too.

Code:

```
<section style="padding-top: 30px;">
        <h4 style="text-transform:uppercase;  display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">Os Convênios podem ser:</h4>

        <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 120px repeat(1, 1fr); grid-gap:30px; padding-top: 30px;">
            
            <div style="background-color: lightgray; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <img src="icons/money_icon.png" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; width: 50px;">
            </div>
            <div>
                <p style="font-weight:bold;">1. Impositivos:</p>
                <p>text</p>
                <p style="font-weight:bold;">2. Autorizativos:</p>
                <p>text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Tip! Use style tags and classes instead of inline style tags.

Comment: Centering things in css: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide. I have used the guide quite a lot myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the div around the image to `display: grid;` and `align-items: center;`, it works.
(i added a .center class to the div arround your image)

```css
.center {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section style="padding-top: 30px;">
        <h4 style="text-transform:uppercase;  display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">Os Convênios podem ser:</h4>

        <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 120px repeat(1, 1fr); grid-gap:30px; padding-top: 30px;">
            
            <div class="center" style="background-color: lightgray; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <img src="icons/money_icon.png" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; width: 50px;">
            </div>
            <div>
                <p style="font-weight:bold;">1. Impositivos:</p>
                <p>text</p>
                <p style="font-weight:bold;">2. Autorizativos:</p>
                <p>text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox in the `div` wrapping your `img` and use `align-items: center` to vertically center your image.
Just add the following style

```
display:flex; align-items:center;
```

to this div

```
<div style="background-color: lightgray; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```